# Choosing generators of a submodule with divisibility properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Looking at an open subset $U$ of the plane, containing $0 \in \mathbb{C}^2$, with coordinates $x$ and $y$.

Given a quotient sheaf $O_U^n \rightarrow T$, with $supp(T)=\lbrace0\rbrace$. Let $K$ be the kernel, then we have: $0\rightarrow K\rightarrow O_U^n \rightarrow T\rightarrow 0$.

Now i'm tying to see the following: There are $g_1,\ldots,g_r\in O_U^n$ such that:

- the $g_j$ generate the submodule $K$
- $g_{n+1},g_{n+2},\ldots,g_r$ are divisible by $x$

The idea seems to be the following: choose generators $g_j$ and to look at the images $\widetilde{g_j}$ of these in $O_U^n/(x)$ via the map $\pi: K\rightarrow O_U^n\rightarrow O_U^n/(x)$.

Now i'm stuck: why can one assume w.l.o.g. that $\widetilde{g_1},\ldots,\widetilde{g_n}$ generate $\pi(K)$?

Should i think of $\pi(K)$ and $O_U^n/(x)$ as sheaves on the one dimensional scheme $\lbrace x=0\rbrace$ in $U$? Because there the local rings are PIDs, which have the property that submodules of free moules of rank $n$ are free of rank $\leq n$. So that $\pi(K)$ has at most $n$ generators, but since $rank(T)=0$,it has exactly $n$. Then the other generators of $K$ vanish in $\pi(K)$ and hence are divisible by $x$.

Is this the basic idea? Or how can i see that $\pi(K)$ has $n$ generators? Are there better ways to get generators with this divisibility property?

This is stated as Lemma 6.1, page 45 in the appendix of J.Li's paper "Algebraic geometric interpretation of Donaldson's polynomial invariants". There it is stated for $n=2$. A copy can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214453683).

Comment: You are missing one step: $\pi(g_j)$ is not automatically zero for $j>n$, but since $\pi(g_1),\dots,\pi(g_n)$ generate $\pi(K)$, you can write $\pi(g_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\pi(g_i)$, and $g_j'=g_j-\sum a_ig_i$ satisfies $\pi(g_j')=0$, i.e., $g_j'$ is divisible by $x$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. A little, but important detail!